# In Elixir why can I not use different notations when creating a map?

Tags: elixir

There are 2 different syntaxes of defining a map:

```
map = %{:a => 1, :b => 2}
#=> %{a: 1, b: 2}
map = %{a: 1, b: 2}   
#=> %{a: 1, b: '2}
```

Using both as follows while defining a map works:

```
map = %{:a => 1, b: 2}
#=> %{a: 1, b: 2}
```

But used in other order throws an error:

```
map = %{a: 1, :b => 2}
#=> ** (SyntaxError) iex:37: syntax error before: b
```

Why?

## EDIT

OS:     Ubuntu 15.4

Elixir: 1.1.1

Comment: This may be a bug in Elixir.

Comment: You may want to add some details.  Version of Elixir,  OS etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [my issue on Github](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/3975) (which I actually should not have opened), this is not a bug.

First answer (which I did not really get):

> It's not a bug, it's the same syntax sugar that is used for keywords
>   on the last argument of a function.
>
> ```
> foo(bar, baz: 0, boz: 1) #=> foo(bar, [baz: 0, boz: 1])
> ```
>
> The map syntax is represented as function call in the AST:
>
> ```
> iex(1)> quote do: foo(bar, baz: 0, boz: 1)
> {:foo, [], [{:bar, [], Elixir}, [baz: 0, boz: 1]]}
> iex(2)> quote do: %{baz: 0, boz: 1}
> {:%{}, [], [baz: 0, boz: 1]}
> ```
>
> That's why the map keyword syntax only works for the last (or only)
>   argument.

And the second answer, which sounded Ok in a sense that I think I got it:

> Simple answer: `b: 2` is syntax sugar for `[b: 2]`, but the sugar only
>   works when it is at the end of a function call or "construct" such as
>   `%{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for the sake of consistency? It's like walking with a flip-flop and a goth boot. You may look fancy, it's still extremely inconvenient.